# And operator doesnt appear to work

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I must be missing something,

my search includes the string long+beach so I expect results to only contain entries where (in this case) the location field contains both long and beach.

```
/indexes/person2/docs?$count=true&$top=100&search=long+beach&searchFields=location
```

plus

```
api-version=2014-07-31-Preview
```

the image I dont have rep to post shows miami beach, florida among others.

I tried setting &searchMode=any with no change.

the column looks like this

```
new { Name = "location",        
Type = "Edm.String",             
Key = false, 
Searchable = true,  
Filterable = true,  
Sortable = true,   
Facetable = true,  
Retrievable = true,  
Suggestions = true },
```

my bad?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an escaping issue. "+" is treated as a space character in most cases by code that handles URL encoding. "+" shouldn't show up literally in the URL but encoded as %2B. More in general, you should escape the search string before adding it to the search= parameter. Most languages have a built-in URL encoding primitive that will do this for you (e.g. Uri.EncodeDataString() in .NET)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. %2B worked for me as well. I think I was thrown off by this page of the Azure Search documentation where it describes the simple query syntax that can be used to refine the search.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798920.aspx

It seems that the simple query syntax is what you would put in the search input box, not what you would send to the API.

Here's an example from my project:

- search=Aberdeen%2Bdistrict    (2 results)
- search=Aberdeen+district      (156 results)